# Unable to deploy php Laravel application with Digital Ocean App getting DB connection timeout during Deployment

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, digital-ocean

I have included a database translation into my Laravel app. And it seems that the build process, particularly `composer autoload-dump` step is trying to connect to the data base however I am getting a connection timeout even though the application is working just fine only the latest deployment is breaking. It seems like the app is unable to make a DB connection during build time. I can understand if the error was that some table is not found but It can't even connect to the DB. [image]

Comment: just run the command `mysql` in your terminal and what output you are getting just post it here

Comment: @BhattAkshay mysql command is not found if you want me to execute it in the command line of the app.

Comment: @BhattAkshay keep in mind that these are build logs of the app.

Comment: Why not run Composer without any scripts during the build process?

Comment: @Adelin than the issue is with your mysql installation. Just check the mysql service is running on your system or not. Check mysql service using this command `sudo service mysql status` if you are using ubuntu.